# Fill an object with indexes from another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have two objects. One that is an array of words, and the other which gives the relation between two words from the first array :

```
nodes = ["apple","cherry","pear","strawberry"]

data = [{word1 : "apple", word2 : "cherry" , weight : "0.1"},
        {word1 : "apple", word2 : "strawberry" , weight : "0.2"},
        {word1 : "cherry", word2 : "pear" , weight : "0.3"},
        {word1 : "cherry", word2 : "strawberry" , weight : "0.4"},
        {word1 : "strawberry", word2 : "pear" , weight : "0.5"}]
```

I would like to create a new object with the structure of data, not with the words but with their indexes. Like so :

```
links =  [{source : "0", target : "1" , value : "0.1"},
          {source : "0", target : "3" , value : "0.2"},
          {source : "1", target : "2" , value : "0.3"},
          {source : "1", target : "3" , value : "0.4"},
          {source : "3", target : "2" , value : "0.5"}]
```

So far I have this :

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < nodes.length; i++) {
     test[i] = nodes.findIndex(d => d == nodes[i]);
}
```

Which gives me this new array, corresponding to the indexes from `nodes` :

```
test = [0,1,2,3]
```

So how do I do now to assign those indexes to the properties in `links`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```js
var nodes = ["apple","cherry","pear","strawberry"];

var data = [{word1 : "apple", word2 : "cherry" , weight : "0.1"},
        {word1 : "apple", word2 : "strawberry" , weight : "0.2"},
        {word1 : "cherry", word2 : "pear" , weight : "0.3"},
        {word1 : "cherry", word2 : "strawberry" , weight : "0.4"},
        {word1 : "strawberry", word2 : "pear" , weight : "0.5"}];

var links = data.map((item) => {
    return {
        source: nodes.indexOf(item.word1),
        target: nodes.indexOf(item.word2),
        value: item.weight
        
    };
});

console.log(links);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#map` on the second array (instead of the first) and `Object.assign` to avoid mutation of the original data.

To reduce the time complexity, a `Map` could be created, which allows to get the index in constant time. That Map can be passed a `this` to the map method. By checking the match for each property, you can make it generic, so there is no hard-coded `word1` or `word2` in the algorithm itself:

```js
const nodes = ["apple","cherry","pear","strawberry"]

const data = [
    {word1 : "apple", word2 : "cherry" , weight : "0.1"},
    {word1 : "apple", word2 : "strawberry" , weight : "0.2"},
    {word1 : "cherry", word2 : "pear" , weight : "0.3"},
    {word1 : "cherry", word2 : "strawberry" , weight : "0.4"},
    {word1 : "strawberry", word2 : "pear" , weight : "0.5"}
];
   
const result = data.map(function(o) {
    return Object.assign(...Object.keys(o).map(key => ({
        [key]: this.has(o[key]) ? this.get(o[key]) : o[key]
    })));
}, new Map(nodes.map( (s,i) => [s,i] ))); 

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array#map()` to create a new array. Get the `indexOf(word1)` and `indexOf(word2)` to replace the current value

```js
const nodes = ["apple","cherry","pear","strawberry"];

const data = [{word1 : "apple", word2 : "cherry" , weight : "0.1"},
        {word1 : "apple", word2 : "strawberry" , weight : "0.2"},
        {word1 : "cherry", word2 : "pear" , weight : "0.3"},
        {word1 : "cherry", word2 : "strawberry" , weight : "0.4"},
        {word1 : "strawberry", word2 : "pear" , weight : "0.5"}];
        
const updatedData = data.map((item) => ({
  source: nodes.indexOf(item.word1),
  target: nodes.indexOf(item.word2),
  weight: item.weight
}));

console.log(updatedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```js
nodes = ["apple", "cherry", "pear", "strawberry"]

data = [{
    word1: "apple",
    word2: "cherry",
    weight: "0.1"
  },
  {
    word1: "apple",
    word2: "strawberry",
    weight: "0.2"
  },
  {
    word1: "cherry",
    word2: "pear",
    weight: "0.3"
  },
  {
    word1: "cherry",
    word2: "strawberry",
    weight: "0.4"
  },
  {
    word1: "strawberry",
    word2: "pear",
    weight: "0.5"
  }
]

var links = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  links.push({
    source: nodes.indexOf(data[i].word1),
    target: nodes.indexOf(data[i].word2),
    value: data[i].weight
  })
}

console.log(links);
```